# Android: SAX parser progress monitoring

Tags: android, xml, sax, saxparser

I have a `SAX` [DefaultHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) which parses an InputStream. I don't know how many elements are in the XML so I can't count them on `endElement` or simmilar. I **do** know the byte length of the `InputStream` (read from the http header) but I can't find a method to get the current bytewise progress of the parsing process.

Is there a way to get the current progress (i.e. bits processed) of the parsing process?

This is how the `DefaultHandler` gets called:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
parser.parse(inputStream, myDefaultHandler);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by writing a [FilterInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) to wrap the existing inputStream.  In the `read()` method of your filter, increment a counter, and provide a getter so that something else can track the current count.

Since the parser may read ahead, this will be approximate, but it's probably the best you can do.

Comment: Quite a good idea, but how do i access my `FilterInputStream` from within the parser? Or should i create a **timer** which calls the getter from somwhere outside and updates the status acordingly?

Comment: Do it from outside, to keep it independent of the parse itself.

Comment: I tried it this way, but the parser does not increment the counter for quite a time and then suddenly consumes all the `InputStream` at once. Any other ideas how this could be achieved?

Comment: I guess the parser is reading ahead a lot after a long wait!  Can't think of anything better right off, except for trying to debug through what's happening.  Add some debug prints in your filter and the handler?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is still searching for the answer,
try to pass the ProgressBar in the constructor of your derived FilterInputStream:

ProgressFilterInputStream.java

```
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.util.Log;


public class ProgressFilterInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

int counter = 0;
ProgressBar progressBar;

public ProgressFilterInputStream(InputStream in, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    super(in);
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.progressBar.setMax(69);  // SET MAX ACCORDIN TO THE DDMS LOGGING MESSAGE
}

@Override
public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) throws IOException {
    progressBar.setProgress(counter++);
    Log.i("PFIS" , "Counter: " + counter);
    return super.read(buffer, offset, count);
}
}
```

I used it in an AsyncTask in my

MyActivity.java

```
final ProgressBar bar_progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.bar_progress);
ProgressFilterInputStream pfis = new ProgressFilterInputStream(getAssets().open("DATA.xml") , bar_progress );           
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(pfis, "UTF-8");
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);

// create the factory
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

// create a parser
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

// create the reader (scanner)
XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();

// instantiate our handler
SaxHandler myHandler = new SaxHandler();

// assign our handler
xmlreader.setContentHandler(myHandler);

// perform the synchronous parse
xmlreader.parse(is);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extended from lx222 answer, I implemented for AsyncTask, ProgressDialog. Late but I hope it may useful with some one :D

```
public class OpenXMLFileOperator extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String filePath;
    private Context context;
    public OpenFileOperator(Context context,String filePath){
        this.context = context;
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {                               
        try {                               
            if (filePath != null) {

                File file = new File(filePath);
                if (file.exists()) {    
                    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    ProgressFilterInputStream pfis = new ProgressFilterInputStream(stream,file.length());
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(pfis, "UTF-8");

                    YourXMLHandle yourHandle = new YourXMLHandle();                 
                    android.util.Xml.parse(reader,yourHandle);

                    stream.close();
                    reader.close();
                    pfis.close();          
                }                
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try{
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading file");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);           
            progressDialog.show();
        }catch(Exception e){
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG,"onPostExecute",e);
        }

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        try{
            if (progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG,"onPostExecute",e);
        }
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { 
        try{
            if (progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG,"onPostExecute",e);
        }

        //TODO: to do something after file loaded
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {        
        int progress = values[0];
        if (progressDialog!=null) {            
            progressDialog.setProgress(progress);
        }
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    private class ProgressFilterInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
        private int counter = 0;
        private long fileLength;
        private int maximum = 100;
        public ProgressFilterInputStream(InputStream in, long fileLength) {
            super(in);
            this.fileLength = fileLength;
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) throws IOException {
            if (counter==0){
                maximum = (int)(fileLength/buffer.length);
            }
            publishProgress((counter++)*100/maximum);
            return super.read(buffer, offset, count);
        }
    }
}
```