# Use progressDialog while parsing xml

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-asynctask, progressdialog

this is my first post on stackoverflow and i'm new to Android. I already searched the forum for a similar question and found this one: [SAX parser progress monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015856/android-sax-parser-progress-monitoring).
But unfortunately it doesn't help me.
My app has to register events in the calendar.
The first thing i achieved was to progress the download of a xml file. You can see this in the attached code.
After that i want the progressDialog to reset and start tracking the progress of the parsing. Would be great if this could be done with a new setMessage() and a percentage value.
After the parsing the data is used to register events in the calendar, again with the same progressDialog.

But at first i want to know how i can track the progress of the parsing. Would be great if have some ideas.
Thank you

```
public class AddCoursesToCalendar extends Activity {

public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 
ArrayList<String> selectedCourses;
public ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_courses_to_calendar);
    if (bundle != null) {
        selectedCourses = bundle.getStringArrayList("selectedCourses");
    }
    new GetDataTask().execute();
}

private Boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
        return true;

    return false;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: 
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
        return progressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

public class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/WIN2.xml";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM = "Item"; 
    private static final String KEY_DAUER = "Duration"; 
    private static final String KEY_ENDE = "End";
    private static final String KEY_SEMESTER_DOZENT = "Location";
    private static final String KEY_RAUMMITSTOCKWERK = "Organizer"; 
    private static final String KEY_START = "Start";
    private static final String KEY_VERANSTALTUNGSNAME = "Subject";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        onCreateDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (isOnline()) {
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL, this);
            long id = 0;

            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml, this);

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                for (String s : selectedCourses) {
                    if (parser.getValue(e, KEY_VERANSTALTUNGSNAME)
                            .contains(s)) {

                        String dozent = null;
                        int spaceIndex = parser.getValue(e,
                                KEY_SEMESTER_DOZENT).indexOf(" ");
                        int lastIndex = parser.getValue(e,
                                KEY_SEMESTER_DOZENT).length();
                        if (spaceIndex != -1) {
                            dozent = parser
                                    .getValue(e, KEY_SEMESTER_DOZENT)
                                    .substring(spaceIndex, lastIndex);
                        }

                        addEvent(
                                parser.getValue(e, KEY_VERANSTALTUNGSNAME),
                                parser.getValue(e, KEY_START),
                                parser.getValue(e, KEY_ENDE),
                                parser.getValue(e, KEY_DAUER),
                                dozent,
                                parser.getValue(e, KEY_RAUMMITSTOCKWERK),
                                id);

                    } id++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AddCoursesToCalendar.this, "No Connection..",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return 1;
    }

      public void doProgress(String value){
            publishProgress(value);
        }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }

    protected void addEvent(String title, String start, String end,
            String duration, String organizer, String location, long id) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        long startInMillis = 0, endInMillis = 0;
        Date startDate, endDate;
        try {
            startDate = format.parse(start);
            endDate = format.parse(end);
            startInMillis = startDate.getTime();
            endInMillis = endDate.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startInMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endInMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Location: " + location);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
        ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
    }

}
```

}

And here the class responsible for the downloading and parsing:

```
public class XMLParser {

public String getXmlFromUrl(String url, AddCoursesToCalendar.GetDataTask task) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        int count;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        long lenghtOfFile = httpEntity.getContentLength();

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        while ((count = httpEntity.getContent().read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
          task.doProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        }

        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xml;
}

public Document getDomElement(String xml, AddCoursesToCalendar.GetDataTask task) {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        is.setCharacterStream(reader);
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return doc;
}

public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
    Node child;
    if (elem != null) {
        if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                    .getNextSibling()) {
                if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    return child.getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

I hope the style of my first post was ok, if not please tell me. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use asynctask to achieve the desired results.

Comment: as far as the 'asking' style is concerned.. its not bad but would be more good if you can come up with a general problem.. like "how to track the parsing of an xml file and show progress? " something like that... :)

Comment: @ Raghunandan: Thanks for your post, i already use asynctask. I want to know how to check the progress of the parsing

Comment: in onPreExecute() you probably want to call showDialog(DLG_PROGRESS) instead of onCreateDialog().

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the XML is **very large** and that the parsing takes **at least** 30 seconds. Otherwise, do yourself a favor and just show an indeterminate indicator ;)

Also, to simplify your code, you may want to use [`URL.openStream()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) instead of a full featured `HttpClient`, and switch to a simple `GET` (since you don't send any parameter I wonder why your server requires a `POST`).

Assumed that the file is a very big one (for a phone, of course), memory usage must be taken into account, and you'll switch from the DOM to [the SAX interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) to process the XML. SAX provides you with an event-based interface while it scans the stream, so you don't have to load the entire file in memory before even starting to process it. Remember, it's a big file and we don't want to run out of memory.

Using SAX we can parse the file while it's downloading, so we can leave network latencies off when computing total and remaining time. At this point, the progress can be approximated by *current item / total*. You can update an internal counter to keep track of the current item, but the problem now is how to compute the total. You can think in terms of

1. Bytes (eg `processed 12932/2791290 Bytes`)
2. Business items (eg `processed 80/291 Items`)

In both cases you need some support from the server. It should provide a `Content-Length` HTTP header or a preamble (called `<manifest>` in this snippet):

```
<root>
  <manifest>
    <total>291</total>
  </manifest>
  ...
  <item id="foobar1">
    <foo>Foo</foo>
    <bar>Bar</bar>
  </item>
  ...
</root>
```

The `AsyncTask` part is quite easy: you can use [`publishProgress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) inside your `doInBackground()`, and in turn it will invoke `onProgressUpdate()` on the UI thread. Inside this method, you will [update the progress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgress%28int%29) of the dialog.

Just a couple of final notes: when the screen is rotated (default configuration assumed), your activity is destroyed, and then recreated. Note that dialogs shown via `Activity.showDialog` are automatically recreated by the system, but the old `AsyncTask` keeps running, and it may keep references to the old (now probably destroyed but not garbage collected) Activity and the old dialog. You have to work on this on your own, there are [too many alternatives](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/4dW4-KMUKJI) (including the Loader framework).

I hope you understand now that the task is not as simple as it might sound, so my advice is to carefully examine business requirements and come up with the simplest and more robust solution - after all, downloading an XML and showing a progress dialog is not the main task of your app ;)